# will my set be thread safe within a ConcurrentMap?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I have the following code. Will it be thread safe even if the set itself is not thread safe?

```
private ConcurrentMap<REGISTRY, Set<CONTACT_ROLES>> proxyRoles = new ConcurrentHashMap<REGISTRY, Set<CONTACT_ROLES>>(); 


    public void setProxyRoles(ConcurrentMap<REGISTRY, Set<CONTACT_ROLES>> proxyRoles) {
        this.proxyRoles = proxyRoles;
    }

    public ConcurrentMap<REGISTRY, Set<CONTACT_ROLES>> getProxyRoles() {
        return proxyRoles;
    }

    public synchronized void addProxyRole(REGISTRY reg, CONTACT_ROLES role) {
        if(proxyRoles.get(reg) == null){
            proxyRoles.put(reg, new HashSet<CONTACT_ROLES>());
        }
        proxyRoles.get(reg).add(role);

    }
```

**EDIT:**

After some very good answers I understand that my solution would not be safe and I googled a bit and found a good replacement for my set in a ConcurrentSkipListSet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Javadoc:

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable
>   expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional
>   specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods
>   corresponding to each method of Hashtable. **However, even though all
>   operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail
>   locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in
>   a way that prevents all access.**

So if 2 threads are accessing the set simultaneously, they won't acquire lock on entire set.

Comment: I suppose it's a R/W lock. If there is nobody writting ¿why do you need exclusive reading?

Comment: @JonAnderOrtizDurántez, I suppose it is about lock stripping.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `Set` is mutable, mutated and accessible outside of the lock. Much better to use immutable `Set`s.

```
public void addProxyRole(REGISTRY reg, CONTACT_ROLES role) {
    Set<CONTACT_ROLES> old =
        proxyRoles.putIfAbsent(reg, Collections.singleton(role));
    if (old == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (;;) {
        Set<CONTACT_ROLES> set = new HashSet<>(old);
        set.add(role);

        if (proxyRoles.replace(reg, old, Collections.unmodifiableSet(set))) {
            return;
        }
        old = proxyRoles.get(reg);
    }
}
```

(Disclaimer: This is Stack Overflow, not compiled or tested.)

Alternative to the loop would be to use a thread-safe `Set`, but that would also require more care for use (for example, you can't just iterate over it).

```
public void addProxyRole(REGISTRY reg, CONTACT_ROLES role) {
    Set<CONTACT_ROLES> set = proxyRoles.get(reg);
    if (set == null) {
        Set<CONTACT_ROLES> newSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
        Set<CONTACT_ROLES> old = proxyRoles.putIfAbsent(reg, newSet);
        set = old==null ? newSet : old;
    }
    set.add(role);
}
```

A `CopyOnWriteArraySet`, say, would also be possible.

Answer (score 1):

No:

Thread 1:

```
for(CONTACT_ROLES role : getProxyRoles().get(REGISTRY)){
//long running iteration
}
```

Thread 2:

```
getProxyRoles().get(REGISTRY).add(null);
```

This will cause a `ConcurrentModificationException` in Thread 1

Comment: good catch. i will add synchronized to getter/setter methods to solve this part. thx!

Comment: Adding synchronized wouldn't solve this problem. Instead, consider returning a defensive copy, or remove the accessor and replace it with methods that access the Map as required.

Answer (score 0):

NO. I think you need to refactor the code/API. Or can return as immutable collection by making a copy http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries.